# Django model loads from one file (views) and not another app's models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Collection` model in a `collection` app, and it loads fine for use in views (below), but when I try to load it for use in a ManyToMany field for another model, I get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Collection' from 'collection.models'`

This project uses allauth, which uses the term `collection` internally, but that doesn't explain (to me) why models from the `collection` app would load from one file and not another.

Ideas?

**views.py** #ok

```
from collection.models import Collection
...

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
  ...
  collection_list = Collection.objects.all().order_by('create_date')
```

**models.py** #errors out

```
from collection.models import Collection
...

class Items(models.Model):
  ...
  field1 = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=255)
  collections = models.ManyToManyField(Collection)
```

Comment: Where do you define the `Collection`? You import it twice, but you never show where the `Collection` itself is defined.

Comment: Might be a _circular import_.

Comment: @kgeo, you don't have to import the related model, you can do: `models.ManyToManyField("collection.Collection")`

Comment: Can you show your directory tree? where are models.py and views.py located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

comment by @NKSM is the fix: don't import the related model, just call it by path, `module.Model`, in this case `models.ManyToManyField("collection.Collection")`

thx

Comment: don't know how to elevate a comment to a fix, so I self-answered. @NKSM actually answered it.